# Как правильно написать правило .htacces?

Tags: .htaccess

вываливается такой адресс 
`http://krymray.ru//oneproduct?id=2` с ошибкой 404 пытаюсь настроить 301  редирект так

```
Redirect 301 /oneproduct?id=2 http://krymray.ru/
```

но правило не срабатывает подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: А вам нужно просто любой несуществующий адрес отправлять на главную? Тогда напишите вот так `ErrorDocument 404 /`

Comment: нет это я для примера писал я знаю страницу на которую по идее должна приводить ссылка

Comment: В смысле, что вы для примера писали, адрес, куда должен попадать пользователь, если страницы не существует, или адрес страницы, которая не существует? :)

Comment: @Станислав конкретно этот должен вести на krymray.ru/balzam-dlya-profilaktiki-vospaleniya-sustavov  но будут и другие с другими id и адресами

Comment: Хм, а на чем крутится сайт, что за движок? В общем-то, все это обычно решается на уровне кода, а не на уровне правил.

Comment: @Sergalas, раз у вас будет много таких переадресаций, то не захламляйте .htaccess. Все переадресации делайте в роутере движка вашего сайта.

Comment: @Visman  как ни странно это обходит движок около 14 таких ошибок

Comment: @Станислав я ответил vismanу

Comment: Ну тогда без взгляда внутрь ничего не получится.

Comment: Я думаю что это битые ссылки потому как я использую алиасы первоначально работало по id  потом было переключено на alias и битые ссылки остались.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ для конкретного примера

> вываливается такой адресс `http://krymray.ru//oneproduct?id=2`

из вопроса:

```
RewriteEngine On
# отлавливаем двойной слеш и oneproduct после него в запросе
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^//oneproduct$
# отлавливаем get параметр
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
# посылаем браузер по новому адресу
RewriteRule . http://krymray.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: а можно несколько раз использовать
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$ к примеру 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=21$

Comment: `^id=(2|21|45|1099|25576879)$`